# problem with pr2 kinect model

Tags: kinect, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to launch

> pr2_kinect_empty_world.launch

However, the kinect on top of the pr2 seems huge. I was able to launch the same file a few days ago, I guess something changed with the model. Anyone happen to realize similar problem?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12451/problem-with-pr2-kinect-model/) by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 288 on 2011-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again,

I guess, I've solved the problem by comparing `kinect_prosilica_camera.urdf.xacro` and `kinect_camera.urdf.xacro` files.

It turns out mesh information wasn't scaled to the meter-scale when the kinect.dae file is generated, but mm-scale instead. It seems scaling can be done after this file is generated by adding scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" at the end of the corresponding line in the urdf files, as shown below,

```
<mesh filename="package://pr2_description/meshes/sensors/kinect_v0/kinect.dae" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
```

Probably, this has been overlooked by the developers in the recent updates.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) with karma: 288 on 2011-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-12-24**:
If so, please file a defect ticket so they can fix it.

**Comment by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on 2012-03-10**:
I came across with this problem again after an upgrade, and decided to open a ticket for this time. But it seems John already created a ticket for this https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/changeset/54208 .

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-03-10**:
both fuerte 1.7.2 and electric 1.6.2 should have the updates, though it might take a day or two for the fuerte debs to be out.